# Magento 2: How to add dynamic custom options in the rest api

Tags: rest, api, magento2

How can add dynamic extra custom options while adding product to the cart in the Magento 2 rest api.

Right now i use this API to add to cart: /V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items

I have used magento observe method with site but it's not working in magento 2 rest API. is there any way to add dynamic extra custom option to the cart.

Comment: Have you get solution.
Could you please help me on this question.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file